# How to configure master -slave Db configuration for hibernate-dropwizard application

Tags: hibernate, dropwizard

I have an application and I want to configure two databases like masterDb and slaveDb and Than for a Api call say /getUseData I want to execute some logic and decide weather the data should be fetched from the masterDb or slaveDb.

I am new to drop wizard so need help here.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to configure master - slave db in my drop wizard application, below are the step I followed:

In my application I am registering hibernate bundle and using the same.

1. provide the slave db configuration in the configuration file (config.yml in my case).

**Sample Config.yml:**

```
Config.yml{
masterDb:
    // configs here
slaveDb:
    // configs here 
}
```

2. Now define a slaveDb variable of type DataSourceFactory (Drop wizard provide this class) in the configuration class for your application (the class which is extending **configuration** class, another dropWizard class)

So till now you will be having two variables lets say, masterDb, SlaveDb  of DataSourceFactory type, the masterDb will be having the config specified for master and the slaveDb will be having the config specified for slave Db in the Config.yml file.

Sample Classes:

public class TestApplicationConfiguration extends

```
DataSourceSelectorConfigurationManager {

    @JsonProperty(“masterDb")
    private DataSourceFactory masterDb = new DataSourceFactory();
    @JsonProperty(“slaveDb")
    private DataSourceFactory slaveDb = new DataSourceFactory();

}
```

**and**

```
public abstract class DataSourceAwareConfigurationManager extends Configuration {

    public abstract DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(DbContextHolder.DbType dbType);
    public abstract DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory();

}
```

**and**

```
public class DBContextHolder {

public enum DbType {
    MDB, SDB,
}

private static final ThreadLocal<DbType> contextHolder = new ThreadLocal<DbType>(){
    @Override
    protected DbType initialValue() {
        return DbType.MDB;
    }
};
public static void setDbType(DbType dbType) {
    if (dbType == null) {
        contextHolder.set(DbType.MDB);
    }
    contextHolder.set(dbType);
}

public static DbType getDbType() {
    return contextHolder.get();
}

public static void clearDbType() {
    contextHolder.remove();
}
}
```

Now if you noticed the contextHolder inside DBContextHolder is a thread local variable and a static variable. So there should not be any issue of synchronisation for multiple threads.

Now when we want the master db we need to set the contextHolder.dbType to MDB for master db and SBD for slave database and once you are done just clear the contextHolder.dbType which will automatically set it to MDB (which is master Database), this will be set on thread level.

And depending on the value of contextHolder.dbType we will either use masterDb or **slaveDb** defined in the dbLocator above.

The basic idea here is to implement/use one of the **getDataSourceFactory()** methods and depending on the dbType return the appropriate dataFactory on run type and use the same.

**We can even create the two different session factory objects one with masterDb config and one with slavDb config and decide which to use on runtime, or just inject the correct db config on runtime.**